# Is there anyway that I can put an movie clip on mouse-over to autoplay my movie?

Tags: javascript, media-player, autoplay

I want to autoplay my video on mouse over.
Can anybody tell me how to make it play via media player or flash player?

PS: Can I play WMV/ASF/MP4 in flash player?

Comment: This url may help you: http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html. I think flash player cannot play wmv,asf,mp4.

Next time pleas add more tags - it shuld help you to get fastee answer.

Comment: What media player? What flash player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have found that it is easiest to use swf files to show movies in the browser for two reasons: Easy to use javascript to control them and they work in old browsers.
(It is easy to convert any movie format to swf).

Also there is the simplistic freedom of the swf, I looked into at the time quite intensively and could not find a single flashplayer that allowed me to control it 100% even if I was willing to spend time researching and programming.

And luckily for you I have a simple JS framework I made myself for embedding and controlling movies in a webpage (should work in all browsers) [Note: I understood JS classes back then even less then I do now so].

```
//http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_03.html

function FlashController(name)
{
    this.flashMovie = this.getFlashMovieObject(name);

    this.getXPos =        function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 0));
                };

    this.getYPos =        function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 1));
                };

    this.getXScale =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 2));
                };

    this.getYScale =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 3));
                };

    this.getNextFrame =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 4));
                };

    this.getCurrentFrame =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 4) - 1);
                };

    this.getTotalFrames =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 5));
                };

    this.getAlpha =        function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 6));
                };

    this.getVisibility =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 7));
                };

    this.getWidth =        function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 8));
                };

    this.getHeight =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 9));
                };

    this.getRotation =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 10));
                };

    this.getTarget =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetProperty("/", 11));
                }
    this.getFramesLoaded =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetPropertyAsNumber("/", 12));
                };

    this.getName =        function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetProperty("/", 13));
                };

    this.getDropTarget =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetProperty("/", 14));
                };

    this.getURL =        function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetProperty("/", 15));
                };

    this.getHighQuality =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetProperty("/", 16));
                };

    this.getFocusRect =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetProperty("/", 17));
                };

    this.getSoundBufTime =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TGetProperty("/", 18));
                };

    this.setXPos =        function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 0, value);
                };

    this.setYPos =        function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 1, value);
                };

    this.setXScale =    function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 2, value);
                };

    this.setYScale =    function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 3, value);
                };

    this.setAlpha =        function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 6, value);
                };

    this.setVisibility =    function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 7, value);
                };

    this.setRotation =    function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 10, value);
                };

    this.setName =        function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 13, value);
                };

    this.setHighQuality =    function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 16, value);
                };

    this.setFocusRect =    function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 17, value);
                };

    this.setSoundBufTime =    function(value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TSetProperty("/", 18, value);
                };

    this.getVariable =    function(path)
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.GetVariable(path));
                };

    this.gotoFrame =    function(num)
                {
                    var loaded = getFramesLoaded();
                    if(num > loaded)
                    {
                        return (this.flashMovie.GoToFrame(loaded));
                    }
                    return (this.flashMovie.GoToFrame(num));
                };

    this.isPlaying =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.IsPlaying());
                };

    this.loadMovie =    function(layerNum, url)
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.loadMovie(layerNum, url));
                };

    this.panPixels =    function(hPx, vPx)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.Pan(hPx, vPx, 0);
                };

    this.panPercent =    function(hP, vP)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.Pan(hP, vP, 1);
                };

    this.getPercentLoaded =    function()
                {
                    var value = Math.round(movieControls.getFramesLoaded()/movieControls.getTotalFrames() * 100);
                    if(isNaN(value))
                    {
                        value = 0;
                    }
                    return (value);
                };

    this.play =        function()
                {
                    this.flashMovie.Play();
                };

    this.rewind =        function()
                {
                    this.flashMovie.Rewind();
                };

    this.setVariable =    function(path, value)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.setVariable(path, value);
                };

    this.zoomRect =        function(left, top, right, bottom)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.SetZoomRect(left, top, right, bottom);
                };

    this.stop =        function()
                {
                    this.flashMovie.StopPlay();
                };

    this.zoom =        function(percent)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.Zoom(percent);
                };

    this.zoomReset =    function()
                {
                    this.flashMovie.Zoom(0);
                };

    this.callFrame =    function(frame)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TCallFrame("/", frame);        
                };

    this.callLabel =    function(label)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TCallLabel("/", label);        
                };

    this.currentLabel =    function()
                {
                    return (this.flashMovie.TCallLabel("/"));        
                };

    this.goToFrame =    function(num)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TGotoFrame("/", num);
                };

    this.goToLabel =    function(label)
                {
                    this.flashMovie.TGotoLabel("/", label);
                };
/*
//Description: Generated as the Flash movie is downloading. The argument type is integer.
    this.OnProgress =    function(percent)
                {
                };

//Description: Generated when the ready state of the control changes.
//The possible states are:
//0=Loading, 1=Uninitialized, 2=Loaded, 3=Interactive, 4=Complete.
    this.OnReadyStateChange =    function(state)
                    {
                    };    

//Description: Generated when an FSCommand action is performed in the movie with a URL
//and the URL starts with FSCommand :
//Use this to create a response to a frame or button action in the Flash movie.
//The argument type is string.
    this.FSCommand =    function(command, args)
                {
                };*/        

    this.nextFrame =    function()
                {
                    var nextFrame = getNextFrame();
                    if(nextFrame >= getTotalFrames())
                    {
                        nextFrame = 0;
                    }

                    goToFrame(nextFrame);
                };
}

FlashController.prototype.getFlashMovieObject = function(movieName)
{
    if (window.document[movieName])
    {
        return (window.document[movieName]);
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
    {
        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
        {
            return (document.embeds[movieName]);
        }
    }
    else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
    {
        return (document.getElementById(movieName));
    }
}

FlashController.embedVideo = function(location, name, filePath, bgColor, width, height)
{
    location.innerHTML += '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" '
                + 'codebase="" id="' + name + '" width=' + width + ' height=' + height + '>'
                + '<param name="movie" value="' + filePath + '">'
                + '<embed play=false swliveconnect=true name="' + name + '" '
                + 'src="' + filePath + '" quality="high" '
                + 'bgcolor=' + bgColor + ' width=' + width + ' height=' + height + ' type="application/x-shockwave-flash">'
                + '</embed></object>';

}
```

To use (I think, it has been awhile):

```
FlashController.embedVideo(nodeToPutItIn, "movie.swf", fullPathToSWF, backGroundColor, width, height); //Or simply hard code into the webpage.
var myMovie = new FlashController("movie.swf");
nodeToPutItIn.onMouseOver = "myMovie.play();";  //never actually done this command before so syntax might be off.
//Note: you have to wait for the movie to load if it is over a slow connection or it is big.
```

If you have any more specific questions then feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi,all, now i am using jwplayer in my project... and it only support MP4 and swf and flv format,can i encode the video via c#?

Comment: Yes, it is a programming language so you can do almost anything with it... But why would you want to program your own encoder when you could just download one?

Comment: Hi Jonathon, i will try your code and let you know... it seems very well !

Comment: Hi Jonathon, our project allowing format is MP4/WMV/ASF, if i am using flash plater,then i need to encode them to swf or flv format so that my player can play, right?

Comment: I think that might depend on the player, I don't know. My way only works with swf files. If you have a set number of movie clips then you should just encode them by hand with some downloaded utility. If you have some situation that you cannot just pre encode your clips then I would assume it should not be hard to get something to encode them automatically (open a new question and someone on this site will know the answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found one way to resolve this by using flow player.

```
    <'a' href="/PlayList/myvideo.flv" style="display: block; width: 520px; height: 330px"
        id="player">
    /<'a'>
    <!-- this will install flowplayer inside previous A- tag. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
            clip: {
                autoPlay: false,
                autoBuffering: true
            },
            onLoad: function () {   // called when player has finished loading
                this.setVolume(30); // set volume property              
            },
            onMouseOver: function () {

                this.play();

            },
            onMouseOut: function () {
                this.stop();
            }
        });

    </script>
```