# IE won't pause Flash SWF file when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, flash, swfobject

I have a simple HTML page that contains two tabs that show/hide content in the same space.

The first tab contains an SWF file that is embedded using SWFObject.js.

When switching between tabs, I would like the SWF file to pause or stop. This works fine on all browsers except IE7+, which is a known problem.

What could be possible resolutions?

A simple solution would be to remove the SWF file from the DOM and re-insert it every time the first tab is selected and loaded.

A better solution would be to pause/stop the SWF file using Javascript or jQuery. How can I go about doing this?

The SWF file is generated using Adobe Captivate 5. Do I need to expose a pause/stop method using ExternalInterface API that Javascript/jQuery can call? Or, is there a standard method for pause/stop that is exposed for all SWF files that I can simply call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

`document.getElementById("movieName").StopPlay();`

then

`document.getElementById("movieName").Play();`

Note: Never used SWFObject.js nor do I know anything about it but this should work for all normal embedding techniques, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177411/is-there-any-way-that-i-can-put-an-movie-clip-on-mouse-over-to-autoplay-my-movie/6179943#6179943) for specific on how I normally embed swf files.

Comment: I've been trying this but both methods return undefined and have no effect on the SWF file.

Comment: Well I wonder if it is how you are embedding it then that is not IE compatible, because I am almost positive that this method is supposed to be.

Comment: See the link in my answer for an example of how to embed a swf into a webpage for IE to like it.

Comment: `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FlashFile.swf" width="100%" height="100%" id="swf_video" style="visibility: visible; "><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></object>`


This is what SWFObject.js spits out to embed my SWF file.

Comment: Yes, if I remember it correctly that is the FF way of doing it IE uses `<embed>` something like that.

Comment: And then I think for some browsers you have to access the `<object>` and others you need the `<embed>`, do a test and see which one but this is what I used to use: `if(window.document[movieName]){return (window.document[movieName]);}if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
 {
  return (document.embeds[movieName]);
 }
 return (document.getElementById(movieName));`

Comment: Try: `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FlashFile.swf" width="100%" height="100%" id="swf_video" style="visibility: visible; "><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><embed play="false" loop="false" menu="false" swliveconnect="true" name="swf_video" src="FlashFile.swf" quality="high" bgcolor=#FFFFFF type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%"></embed></object>`

Comment: Nope. Still no results. The file continues to play unaffected.

Comment: Well I just noticed something else.
You probably what to remove the `<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never">` or change it to true or something like that. It sounds like this would not allow you to control the swf through JS, so turning it off might solve all your issues.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I ended up resorting to just removing the Flash object from the DOM on tab unload and reinserting it on tab load.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [CaptivateController utility](http://pipwerks.com/2010/08/23/captivatecontroller-updated-to-support-adobe-captivate-5/); it was designed specifically for controlling Captivate SWFs via JavaScript.

Comment: I just re-read your post and realized what you're asking is to pause *then hide* the SWF then be able to resume from where you left off after making the SWF visible again. Unfortunately, browsers vary in their handling of SWFs that have been hidden from view. Some browsers will always resume from the beginning when the SWF is made visible again. The only workaround would be for you to script a bookmarking feature and force the SWF to use the bookmark after the SWF reloads. A messy workaround, to say the least.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily looking to pause the video. Just stopping the flash on tab switch would have sufficed.
This was to address an IE bug where if the Flash has audio and you switch tabs on the same page, you keep on hearing the audio as the Flash is still playing under the hidden div.